# Initial Value Problem: Integration Clarification

Tags: calculus, integration

I wanted to clarify an integration procedure. It relates to Example 7, found here:

https://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/MA102-5.5.4-Equations-and-Initial-Value-Problems.pdf

When I integrate the acceleration function:

a = -4sin2t

I get:

v = 4cos2t^2 / 2 + C

Can someone help clarify why the link shows:

v = 4cos2t / 2 + C?

Answer (score 1):

you have to solve the integral $$-4\int \sin(2t)dt$$ Setting $$z=2t$$ and we get $$dt=\frac{1}{2}dz$$ and our integral will be $$-2\int \sin(z)dz=-2\cdot (-1)\cos(z)+C$$

Comment: Why didn´t you use variable $z$ in the last line ?

Comment: it was only a typo of mine thank you for the hint!

Comment: Thank you for this... I see now where I was going wrong :)